# Is there a way to specify number of partitions while read data (spark.read.jdbc) from database(Oracle) without specifying lower and upper bound?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to read data from Oracle database using Spark.read.jdbc. If I specify lowerbound, upperbound and numpartitions, last partition might be larger than executor memory. Is there a way to numpartitions without specifying lowerbound and upperbound (like sqoop)?

Answer (score 0):

Give a `columnName` which is numeric, contains unique values like the PK or UK and has an index on it. Index is optional for performance.

It will partition your data uniformly because data is naturally distributed in that column.

```
spark.read.jdbc(
  url: String,
  table: String,
  columnName: String,
  lowerBound: Long,
  upperBound: Long,
  numPartitions: Int,
  connectionProperties: Properties)
```